# clojure.contrib.duck-streams FileNotFoundException, why?

Tags: clojure

`user=> (use '[clojure.contrib.duck-streams])
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/contrib/duck_streams__in
it.class or clojure/contrib/duck_streams.clj on classpath:  (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)`

Clojure.contrib is in CLASSPATH still it is throwing Exception. Do I need some other Jar?

Comment: i'm assuming your running clojure 1.3?

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt No, 1.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend using leiningen to sort this out.

try the `lein repl` command to get a quick repl with a working classpath.

According to this message:

http://osdir.com/ml/clojure/2010-10/msg00834.html

clojure.contrib.duck-streams has been deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

Use `clojure.java.io` instead, it's included with 1.2.